# p-cycles in Galois group

Tags: galois-theory

Suppose $f$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ of prime degree $p$ and let $\alpha$ be one of its roots. Then we know that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ has degree $p$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and therefore (by the Galois correspondence) the Galois group of $f$ contains a $p$-cycle. My question is if there's an easy way to find that $p$-cycle for a particular $f$.

The motivation for this question is that it's not apriori (without Galois theory) clear to me at all that such a permutation of the roots should exist, i.e. that it should induce an automorphism of the splitting field.

Comment: That it is not clear is reasonably understandable. It took a young troubled genius to make it clear.

Comment: @uniquesolution I probably get what you mean. That finding that automorphism for a general case is essentially as difficult as solving (or even deciding the solvability of) a particular polynomial equation.

Comment: So even for a concrete example, there's no way to "see" the automorphism? E.g. take the classic example of a quintic with 3 real roots. Or even the simplest one $x^3 - 2$.

Comment: Well, the $x^3 - 2$ case is too simple, since the extension is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3, 2^{1/3})$ so it's quite clear what the automorphisms (and therefore cycles) are. Even though... even in this simple case it's not apriori clear that "rotating" the roots would be an automorphism.